# How can I mock command handler call from another command handler

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have **UpdateHandler** and I would like to test does it work or not. But, I have an issue, I don't know how to mock **CanChangeHandler**.

I've created another test for this handler. In **UpdateHandler** I want to get **canChangeResponse** with Can is true/false, and based on that I want to test **UpdateHandler** that **canChangeResponse** is **null**.

I've tried a few different ways to mock both, **commandDispather** and **CanChangeHandler**, 
but it just hasn't worked.

Does anybody have experience with similar issues?

My code is below (I've put only the relevant code to show what is the issue).

```
public UpdateHandler(ICommandDispatcher commandDispatcher)
{
    _commandDispatcher = commandDispatcher;
}

public override SimpleResponse Handle(CreateScheduleCommand command)
{
    try
    {
        var canChangeResponse = _commandDispatcher.Get<CanResponse>(
            new CanChangeCommand(command.Id));

        if (!canChangeResponse.Can)
        {
            return new SimpleResponse(canChangeResponse.Why);
        }

        //update code comes here and I want to test this

        return new SimpleResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _log.CommandError(command, e);
        return new SimpleResponse(Resources.GeneralFailure);
    }
}
```

---

Setup for test:

```
_container = new WindsorContainer();
new ContainerConfiguration(_container).Apply();

_container.Install(new MongoRepositoriesInstaller(_mongoConnectionString, typeof(User).Assembly));

_container.Install(new CommandHandlersInstaller());
//new CommandProcessorConfiguration(_container).Apply();

var commandDispatcher = new Mock<ICommandDispatcher>();
commandDispatcher.Setup(x => x.Get<CanResponse>(new CanUpdateCommand())).Returns(new CanResponse { Can = true });

var canUpdateHandler = new Mock<ICommandHandler<CanUpdateCommand, CanResponse>>();
canUpdateHandler.Setup(x => x.Handle(new CanUpdateCommand())).Returns(new CanResponse { Can = true });
_container.Register(Component.For<ICommandHandler<CanUpdateCommand, CanResponse>>().Instance(canUpdateHandler.Object));
```

Test:

```
[Ignore]
[Test]
public void Update()
{
    // Arrange

    var commandDispatcher = Container.Resolve<ICommandDispatcher>();
    var handler = new UpdateHandler(commandDispatcher);

    // Act

    var response = handler.Handle(new UpdateCommand());

    // Assert

    Assert.IsFalse(response.HasErrors);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to use an IOC container, in your Unit Tests, which add some added complexity to deal with. You can easily set-up a stub on ICommandDispature.

```
        var stubCommandDispatcher = new Mock<ICommandDispatcher>();
        stubCommandDispatcher.Setup(x => x.Get<CanResponse>
            (It.IsAny<CanChangeCommand>()))
            .Returns(new CanResponse() {Can = true});

        var stubScheduleCommand = new Mock<CreateScheduleCommand>();
        var sut = new UpdateHandler(stubCommandDispatcher.Object);

        var r = sut.Handle(stubScheduleCommand.Object);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. 

Also, I've found that line below can help as well.

commandDispatcher.SetReturnsDefault<CanResponse>(new CanResponse { Can = true });